# Using non-printable characters as a delimiter in PHP?

Tags: php, delimiter

When storing an array in a file, I implode it with a delimiter, but if any of the values had the delimiter in it, then this would destroy that value (and give me 2 smaller ones).

Is it good practice to use non-printable characters as a delimiter? And if so, how to do that?

Comment: It actually depends on your use case. What's the data, how do you want to read it, and did you anticipate a specific context to resort to non-printable delimiters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It used to be a practice in the 80s. Specifically the ASCII charset had some non-printable symbols just for that very purpose.

```
   034   28    1C    FS  (file separator)        134   92    5C    \  '\\'
   035   29    1D    GS  (group separator)       135   93    5D    ]
   036   30    1E    RS  (record separator)      136   94    5E    ^
   037   31    1F    US  (unit separator)        137   95    5F    _
```

You *could* use them like `"\036"` in PHP, and later split up by them. But JSON or phps serialize() format or even XML are more advisable for webapps than a binary format.

Comment: +1 I never new about those characters, thanks for the info. Would be better to use RS (chr(30)) i guess, rather than tab as in my answer.

Comment: @vascowhite, you may realize this, but whatever character you use, you're still susceptible to deliberately crafted user input containing it.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen Only if the data has come from the user. Not all data does.

Answer (score 2):

To store any data structure inside a file you should use [`serialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to store and [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to restore the data structure again.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose there are many serialization formats that have specifications for how to deal with characters with special meaning in the serialized format. Use one of them, for example [JSON](http://php.net/json_encode), [serialized PHP](http://php.net/serialize) or [CSV](http://php.net/fputcsv).

Comment: Yes, but explode/implode is 3x faster than serialize on my benchmarks, and speed is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its the best practice, but if you had to do this for some reason then the example below shows a way of doing it using the tab character as a delimiter. This table may be useful for you http://www.asciitable.com/.

```
$testArray = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
$delimiter = chr(9);
$imploded = implode($delimiter, $testArray);
var_dump($imploded);
var_dump(explode($delimiter, $imploded));
```

Maybe better to use `$delimiter = chr(30)` as in @mario's answer.